# Slow query in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query that is taking more than 1 hour to run.

```
SELECT 
    RES.NUM_PROCESS,
    RES.ID_SYSTEM
FROM 
    RESTRICTED_PRECESS RES   -- 16'000 records
WHERE   
    RES.ID_SYSTEM <> 'CYFV'  
    AND RES.NUM_PROCESS NOT IN (SELECT PR.NUM_PROCESS  
                                FROM PRECESS PR  -- 8.000.000 records
                                WHERE PR.ID_SYSTEM = RES.ID_SYSTEM)
```

The indexes for the tables are already ok.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX1_PROCESS] ON [dbo].[PRECESS] 
(
    ID_SYSTEM ASC
)
INCLUDE(NUM_PROCESS)
```

here's the execution plan

[image]

Is there any way to make this `SELECT` return records faster?

Thank you.

Comment: What indexes do you have on the tables? Can you post the query plan (use Paste the Plan).

Comment: `The indexes for the tables are already ok` ... What _are_ the indices you have on these tables?

Comment: @Larnu - Yeah, I saw that (deleted the comment).  Still a lot of records.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for query tuning advice, however, does not include the DDL for the objects involved, along with their indexes, and the query plan in a consumable format (such as by using [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). It therefore lacks the information to be able to performance tune their query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I attached the execution plan

Comment: @Larnu yes, there are many records.

Comment: @Keny I never questions to the number of **rows**. I asked you to provide the indexes and the query plan in a *consumable* format. You have 2 scans there, suggesting you don't have any indexes that are helping.

Comment: @Keny, your indexes are not ok. Add your DDL and upload the plan to Past The Plan as asked.

Comment: Side note: I recommend against `NOT IN` with subqueries. I has documented behaviour that many don't read about in relation to `NULL` values. You're better off with a `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: *"The indexes for the tables are already ok."* If the only `INDEX` you have is that, then your indexes for the tables are certainly not "ok". There is no index on `RESTRICTED_PRECESS` to help the RDBMS to here.

Comment: @Larnu I have already created an index for the RESTRICTED_PRECESS table, and it is INDEX SEEK.

But querying is still taking time

My biggest problem now is the PROCESS table, as you can see is INDEX SCAN.

Comment: The image you have shows no seeks and only scans, @Keny .

Comment: ok, so how do I create an INDEX SEEK in the PROCESS table?

Comment: Have you had a look at the answer from @TimBiegeleisen ?

Comment: Yes, that's why I put the execution plan, to show the indexes

Answer (score 2):

I will just go ahead and suggest what might be helpful indices here for the two tables:

```
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON RESTRICTED_PRECESS (ID_SYSTEM, NUM_PROCESS);
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON PRECESS (ID_SYSTEM, NUM_PROCESS);
```

The index on the outer table `RESTRICTED_PRECESS` should speed up the `WHERE` clause, and it also completely covers the `SELECT` clause.  The index on the table `PRECESS` in the subquery should speed it up as well.